# iOS Photos framework unable to get image data / UTI

Tags: ios, objective-c, photosframework

When requesting images from the Photos Framework I manage to get all but the last 64 correctly. The last ones always return nil for the `dataUTI` and `imageData` in the following code. Whilst attempting to figure out what was going on I found that the `PHAsset` knows exactly what the UTI is, but is reporting it to me as nil.

Anyone else seen this?

You can see I've made my code access the asset's UTI when it's reported as nil so that my app can determine if it's a gif or not but this isn't an advisable way of doing it and I never get the `imageData` anyway so it's not a huge amount of help!

```
PHFetchOptions* fetchOptions = [[PHFetchOptions alloc] init];
fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"creationDate" ascending:NO]];
PHFetchResult *allPhotosResult = [PHAsset fetchAssetsWithMediaType:PHAssetMediaTypeImage options: fetchOptions];

[allPhotosResult enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(PHAsset *asset, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {

    PHImageRequestOptions* options = [[PHImageRequestOptions alloc] init];
    options.synchronous = NO;
    options.networkAccessAllowed = YES;
    options.deliveryMode = PHImageRequestOptionsDeliveryModeHighQualityFormat;

    [[PHImageManager defaultManager] requestImageDataForAsset: asset options: options resultHandler:^(NSData *imageData, NSString *dataUTI, UIImageOrientation orientation, NSDictionary *info) {
         NSString* val = [asset valueForKey: @"uniformTypeIdentifier"];
         if( !dataUTI )
         {
             dataUTI = val;
         }
    }];
}];
```

EDIT:
I forgot to mention that the missing image creation dates aren't the most recent images and seem spread out. Actually, even the Photos app doesn't seem to show them, based on their creation date. But there doesn't seem to be anything that *should* be in that their positions looking at the neighboring images of where their creation dates would place them.

Comment: Are these last 64 images present on disk? Can you check that? There is an option in iCloud settings called optimize my iphone, it purges out any images from disk that are were not clicked within the last 30 days.

Comment: I don't believe so, their creation dates are further in the past. Actually, forgot to mention that even the Photos app doesn't seem to show them, based on their creation date... But there doesn't seem to be anything that should be in that position looking at he neighbouring images...

Comment: Can you try setting networkAccessAllowed property PHImageRequestOptions to YES?

Comment: It is already and I've tried it on a good connection

Comment: Can you print all attributes returned by this API as well as the asset? Also it would be great if you could provide more code?

Comment: Yeah I can give an example later, will add in some additional code too

Comment: I've added a bit more code @jarora.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not much of an answer here so happy for someone else to take a bash at explaining it!

Looking at the creation dates of the missing assets I managed to track one down in the Photos app that was missing from my app. It had a thumbnail but when I selected it it did the circular download indicator to pull down the data but then trying to open it in my app's Action Extension (just let's you preview the gif's animation in the Photos app or elsewhere) a popup appeared that said there was an error preparing it. Which I've not seen before but clearly something was going wonky with iCloud.

Previously I was requesting the `PHImageRequestOptionsVersionUnadjusted` in my app but switching it to `PHImageRequestOptionsVersionOriginal` seems to have fixed it....?